# typescript compiler erroneously complains that 'condition will always return true' when an accessor is used in the condition

Tags: typescript

I experimented with typescript getter/setter [accessors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors) when I found what looks to me like a typescript compiler bug. Apparently the compiler doesn't treat accessors as method calls when statically evaluating conditions. The result is that it complains about the condition being always true when it clearly will *not* be always true.

The [following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCCuBzRBPAwgewLYAcCWIApgE7QDeAUNNdAC6EAetAXNBLcXgHaLQC80AOQAVABaFoAMwwNoAK3i4YGAG4k646OABeKaABMMiQQG4qNHJxVh60HBgh5aeDF1ZdFAI3UCADGfNqSzxrW0RCWmhgeGJiQi5aAAoASlZ2Th5yQJpqONoYrg08CAA6eiYAbVpRYpL7R2dXAF0zHIBfCmz6dhTWFQw8fSycnLxJaETBCsFoAEI+AWra6Nj42mTskZo8gtat6ABqA6XS+qcXLj2tsYnBJpn5xZrSlbiEjf2R4FcIDCISkBGRIAAxOJVea1YABIyGCIQk2sDkldoB0OkA) demonstrate the problem:

```
class BuggyCompiler {
    text: string = 'The fox jumps over the lazy dog';
    private position: number = 0;

    private get current(): string {
        return this.text[this.position];
    }

    test(): void {
        if ('[' !== this.current)
            return;
        ++this.position;

        // This condition will always return 'true' since the types
        // '"]"' and '"["' have no overlap.(2367)
        //  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        if (']' !== this.current)
            console.log(`this.current: ${this.current}`);
    }
}
```

I first encountered this error while working on a VS-Code extension (reported by VS-Code while editing the VS-Code extension). Apparently I can execute the code in 'playground' even though the error is reported, but VS-Code refuses to execute.

The fact that I can execute the code in 'playground' makes me wonder if the error is reported by typescript compiler or another tool.

Also note that replacing the condition:

```
        if (']' !== this.current)
            console.log(`this.current: ${this.current}`);
```

with:

```
    let ch = this.current;
    if (']' !== ch)
        console.log(`this.current: ${this.current}`);
```

eliminates the error.

What should I do to avoid this kind of error being reported ? Is it a typescript compiler bug ?

I am no typescript expert, so before reporting an issue to the typescript project I would like confirmation this is a real compiler bug.

[image]

Comment: Good question, but please reduce the example code to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It seems you're right. Maybe it worth opening an issue on [typrecript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript).

Comment: If you simplify a little bit your code, the error goes away: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=9&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuAnAlgOwOYAUyIgU0WgG8Aoac6ePAD3gC5oIk11oBeaAck4G4yKADigBuYKtAEB7CMnjJJqBqgCuAWwBGBdtAAMffuSHJR49HnjRgyxIjyp4ACgCUDJigzEDFcrfjXUlAAWyBAAdFS0ANrwwWFSMnIKALp83gC+JF5UTM4MwpLIACae3t7IAGbQDpyRnNAAhGwcMSGhVjZ28E5epRTAChCSIHihIJLoDgAGLWHttvYMACREM23W8-Bpk06pvdAA1Pur8bLyqLu9FVWcSXWNzbFrHfbde6X9qIPDo+NTq3OdJYrR4A+xbHZeDIZEjDCzAbSoPAAdzgzAw2FwBGcfGA4RoFg4nAAKoE8NBypJqNAAFZqAQwSTCLSRdRDQpJGJk8AALwAntBCuNIgB6VkgdmhTgkXHZRxOIA). That's weird

Comment: @julianobrasil your code is different, I have a return if the first condition is true, that you miss in your code. If you add the return your code will also report the error.

Comment: @julianobrasil This is the reason why I thinks the static analysis doesn't consider accessor as method calls but rather as member access and assume their value is not changed when modifying another member... (which is wrong obviously)

Comment: And if you reinforce the type, the compiler allows you to proceed (possible workaround): `']' !== (this.current as string)`. I think it gets lost and stop judging that statement.